# Flexbox width not behaving consistently across browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I need the container with 85% max-width to be centered, while the flex grid wraps the item.

If the flex grid is less than the max-width, the container adapts the computed content width rather than just using the 85% of container (using the "max-content" value).

Sample content:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.centered {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.grids {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.box {
  margin: 8px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  max-width: 128px;
  background: green;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grids">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a reproduction in codepen](https://codepen.io/lxsmnsyc/pen/abbJLqa). This works correctly on **Chrome** and **Safari** but this doesn't work correctly on **Firefox**.

Comment: max-content require a prefix with firefox `width:-moz-max-content`

Comment: `max-width` and `width` are conflicting with each other. Remove `width` property from `.container `

Comment: awork around with grid and or with extra elements could do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYYxaBO unless i totally misunderstood. I run none of the browsers where you tell us it works as you expect.